# How many ways can we define prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, definition

So the other day I was in an interview for a PhD program, one of the professors asked me to give the definition of a **prime number**. So I gave him the following usual definition-

> Any positive number $p>1$ is called a prime number if the only divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$ itself.

Then he asked me what are the other definitions of a prime number? To which I had no answer as I don't know any other definition. Then he said the following-

> A natural number $n > 1$ is a prime number if and only if $(n-1)!=-1 (\text{mod} ~n).$

Which is basically the statement of **Wilson's theorem.**

My question is, can we use these kind of results//theorems as definitions of prime numbers?

If I say, *"for any natural number $n>1$, if $\phi(n)=n-1,$ then $n$ is a prime, where $\phi$ is Euler's Totient function."* would also qualifies to be a definition of prime number?

If so what are the other definitions of prime numbers?

Thanks for any valuable input.

**Edit**: So from the comments I got several examples, thanks for that, I got the idea. So now I want an answer to the question, **can we use these kind of results//theorems as definitions of prime numbers?**

Comment: If we allow Wilson's theorem to be considered *a* definition of a prime number - instead of viewing it as a corollary of primality by what one could call "the" definition (which you gave) - then it feels like any of the foolproof primality tests would warrant a valid definition of prime.

Comment: A prime number could be defined as the generators of the [prime ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_commutative_rings) of $\mathbb_{Z}$.

Comment: Or the positive integers for which $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ is a field.

Comment: (Positive) integers $n$ for which $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain.

Comment: I wonder if this question would fit well with one of those "big-list" tags and the answers just a big community wiki post with everything people can possibly think up. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: One of the most important ways you can define a prime integer $p$ is as an integer for which the implication $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ holds for all integers $a,b$.

Comment: Or the integers $p>1$ for which $p\mid ab\ \implies\ p\mid a\ \vee\ p\mid b$.

Comment: Or the positive elements of $\Bbb{Z}$ that are irreducible.

Comment: The points of discontinuity of $\pi(x) = R(x) - \sum_\rho R(x^\rho) -1/\ln(x) - \tan^{-1}(\pi/\ln x)/\pi$, where $R$ is the Riemann R function and $\rho$ is a nontrivial zero of the zeta function.

Comment: Or the positive integers $p$ for which every group of order $p^2$ is abelian.

Comment: If you possess the [Matrix of Leadership](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_Leadership) then you are a Prime...(autobot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like Wilson's theorem (a positive integer is a prime if and only if ....)
any equivalent statement is handy when we want to show a number is prime.
If we encountered a number in a situation where congruence condition of its factorial is available then it is good to use that for testing primality.

Logically any of the "if-and-only-if theorems"  can be taken as a definition.

But human beings who discover theorems are not logical machines.
While learning a subject, a formulation that uses less preliminary concepts is helpful; So the theorem  "$n$ is a prime iff $Z/nZ$ is a field",  is not
suitable as a definition.

Accepted textbooks  use that formulation of definition  which makes it easy to digest and understand the subject, even if the subject did not evolve that way historically!

Answer (score 2):

Take the statements of any of the deterministic pirmality tests. Each of their converse gives a new definition of primes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to elaborate on the comment that a number $p$ is prime if $p \mid ab$ means either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

Consider for example $p = 14$. That's not actually prime, but indulge me for a minute. Check that $14 \mid 112$ and $112 = 7 \times 16$. However, $14 \nmid 7$ and $14 \nmid 16$ either. Therefore $14$ is not prime. However, $2$ and $7$ are prime, since for any choice of $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = 112$, you will see that either $a$ or $b$, maybe both, are divisible by $2$ and/or by $7$.

The definition you gave is equivalent to saying if $ab = p$, then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit (like $-1$). And that definition is fine until you venture out to domains of numbers other than $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, are the numbers $3 \pm 2 \sqrt{10}$ prime? Yes, they are. How about $\sqrt{10}$? It satisfies the $ab = p$ definition but not the $p \mid ab$ definition.